# Obtener de una lista un solo dato

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad, deseamos tomar de una lista un solo dato, el cual será usado posteriormente. este es el código que estamos utilizanado:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registro/Equipo", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo")]
    public string GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo(int Registro)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro);
            var q = from a in t
                    select new
                    {
                        a.equipo,
                    };
            return q.FirsOrDefault(a => a.equipo);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return EquipoSalida;
        }
    }
```

Nos esta saliendo un error en esta línea:

```
                  a.equipo,
```

Este es el error:

Error   CS1061  'char' does not contain a definition for 'equipo' and no accessible extension method 'equipo' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Nosotros deseamos obtener un solo dato de tipo string, el cual será utilizado dentro de nuestro aplicativo para ser ingresado en otro método. Por ello, hacemos la consulta en la base de datos para obtener la lista y de ella tomar el dato del equipo.

Agradecemos su ayuda

Comment: Tu funcion se llama a si misma? o hay un error en ese codigo. Si es un error, de que tipo es t?

Comment: Gracias por la observación gbianchi, realmente t es GetLlantasSalidasRegistro. Hice la corrección en el código, pero el error persiste.

Comment: ok.. y eso que devuelve?? que es t???

Comment: t es otro método que devuelve una lista en la cual esta el campo "equipo", campo que necesito para ingresar a otro método.

Comment: estas seguro que t es una lista? si t es una lista, para que proyectas esa lista en otra lista (q) para luego quedarte con un campo solo del primer elemento de la primer lista? no tiene mucho sentido...

Comment: yo necesito tomar solo un campo de la lista, campo que solo debe tener un dato. Realmente en el momento, no se como tomar solo un campo de la lista y por ello, estoy tratando de esta forma. el parámetro "Registro" hace que me devuelvan la fila mas reciente de la lista y de esa fila solo necesito el campo "equipo". Ese campo luego lo necesito en otro método que pide un dato "equipo" de tipo string. Por eso estoy buscando como obtenerlo. Pero la finalidad es tener ese string para usarlo en el otro método.

Comment: No es lo que dije.. yo entendi lo que dijiste... ahora vuelvo a preguntar.. t es una lista?? si es una lista, porque simplemente no te quedas con el primer elemento de la lista (sin usar un query linq) y luego te quedas con el campo que vos queres?? pero segun el error, t no es una lista...

Comment: Un `=>` indica que es una función. `FirsOrDefault` acepta una función que retorne un `bool`, pero tu tienes `a => a.equipo` que retorna otra cosa (un string creo). `FirsOrDefault` con una función dentro es lo mismo que un `Where` + `FirsOrDefault()` . Cambia todo ese código por `return GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo(Registro).FirsOrDefault()?.equipo;`

Comment: Que devuelve el método GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo(Registro)??

Comment: Hola Japy, ya corregi la pregunta ya que realmente no es GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo(Registro) sino GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro). Este me devuelve una lista con varios campos, entre los cuales esta el campo "equipo". Yo deseo tomar solo ese dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo, primero agradecer a gbianchi por sus comentarios lo cual nos permitió dar una mejor solución al error que se estaba presentando.
Necesitaba el campo equipo para utilizarlo en otro método, para ellos simplemente en el método donde necesitaba el dato equipo, invoco la lista y toma el dato así:

```
var t1 = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro);
            var q1 = t1.FirstOrDefault();
            string? Equipo = q1.equipo;
```

La clave fue entender que dentro del método final, podía obtener el dato equipo, invocando el otro método que lo contenía.

Comment: Llevas bastante tiempo en el sitio.. no agregues otra respuesta... Este metodo, de aca, es justamente lo que te describimos en comenatrios. Si entendiste que hace, bien!

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo, logre obtener el dato de tipo de la lista t, modificando el método asi:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registro/Equipo", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo")]
    public string GetLlantasSalidasRegistroEquipo(int Registro)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro);
            var q = from a in t
                    select 
                        a.equipo;
            return q.FirstOrDefault();                
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return EquipoSalida;
        }
    }
```

Como pueden notar, en el select solo menciono el campo de mi intéres y luego retorno con FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir, estas reiterando sobre algo que ya sabes que es... podias hacer t.FirstOrDefault() (te devuelve lo mismo) y luego quedarte con el campo que querias de ahi algo asi como var q = t.FirstOrDefault(); return q.equipo;... y ademas, podias hacerlo todo en una sola linea return GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro).FirstOrDefault().equipo; tambien podrias haber implementado un metodo que solo te devuelva ese campo en el objeto.. me parece que te estas complicando

Comment: gbianchi muchas gracias por sus observaciones. Como entenderas, en el mundo de la programación hay muchas formas de hacer algo. Unas formas van a ser complicadas y otras simples, todo es de acuerdo a la experiencia que tenga el programador. Agradecemos todos sus recomendaciones y las vamos a tener presente.

Comment: Te dijeron lo mismo en un comentario. Y si, hay multiples formas de hacer algo, pero lo que estas haciendo aca, y no siguiendo las recomendaciones que te dieron, es demostrar que no estas entendiendo que hace cada parte, o que pasa en cada pedazo de codigo que estas escribiendo. Me gustaria que expliques este codigo (ya que asi como esta, la respuesta no es valida) para que demuestres que realmente entendes lo que haces. De paso, fijate lo que te pusieron en comentarios (sobre todo a Yussef) que te soluciono esto hace rato...

Comment: Entendido gbianchi, muchas gracias voy a revisar el código y buscar hacerlo de forma que lo pueda entender y explicar en la respuesta que voy a dar.